# Unable to call local directory call in python

Tags: python, modular-design

I have created base folder as test_proj then inside test_proj new test folder created with class file hello1.py with method log. Then from test_proj am trying to call this log method but unable to do so.. facing error as ModuleNotFoundError. Screen shot is provided. Any help is highly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyqIo.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking to an image, please edit your post and type out the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an empty `__init__.py` file in the test folder.

The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages. This prevents directories with a common name, such as string, unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the **all** variable, described later.

Comment: see the directory structure here. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html